# Is it possible to model building a gcc cross compiler in conan 2.0

Tags: conan

I'd like to make a conan package for a gcc cross compiler.  In order to build a cross gcc toolchain from scratch you need to:

- Build a version of gcc using `--without-headers`.   This results in a compiler that cannot create normal binaries, but is good enough to build glibc
- Use that limited gcc to build glibc
- Build a full gcc, passing a reference to the glibc install using `--sysroot=`

I'd like to model this whole build process as a conan dependency graph.

Below is what I've come up with so far, with all the details of actually building gcc and glibc left out.

`conan install cc --build=missing` works.   This would build a normal compiler targeting the same platform it's running on.

`conan install cc --build=missing pr:macos-x86_64 -o os_target=Linux -o arch_target=x86_64` does not work.  I get the error `ConanException: Tried to define 'os' setting inside recipe`

Is there any way I can make the `cc` package depend on a `libc` package built for a entirely different profile?

*`cc/conanfile.py`*

```py
import os
from typing import Any

from conan import ConanFile


class CompilerConanfile(ConanFile):
    name : Any = "cc"
    version : Any = "1.0"
    description : Any = "c compiler"
    license : Any = "TBD"
    homepage : Any = "TBD"
    options : Any = {
        "os_target": ["Windows", "Linux", "Macos"], 
        "arch_target": ["x86", "x86_64"],
        "libc":[True, False]}
    default_options : Any = {"libc": True, "os_target": "Macos", "arch_target": "x86_64"}
    build_requires: Any
    requires: Any

    def configure(self):
        # record target information in options
        if settings_target := getattr(self, "settings_target", None):
            self.options.os_target = self.options.os_target or settings_target.os
            self.options.arch_target = self.options.arch_target or settings_target.os

    def requirements(self):
        if self.options.libc:
            self.requires("sysroot/1.0", options={
                "os_target": self.options.os_target,
                "arch_target": self.options.arch_target,
            })

    def generate(self):
        if self.options.libc:
            sysroot = self.dependencies.get('sysroot').conf_info.get('user.sysroot.root')
            self.output.highlight(f"sysroot is at {sysroot}")
```

*`sysroot/conanfile.py`*

```py
import os
from typing import Any

from conan import ConanFile

class SysrootConanfile(ConanFile):
    name : Any = "sysroot"
    version : Any = "1.0"
    description : Any = "sysroot files for a cross compiler"
    license : Any = "TBD"
    homepage : Any = "TBD"
    options : Any = {
        "os_target": ["Windows", "Linux", "Macos"], 
        "arch_target": ["x86", "x86_64"]
    }
    default_options : Any = {"os_target": "Macos", "arch_target": "x86_64"}
    settings : Any = ("os", "arch")
    build_requires: Any
    requires: Any
    conf_info: Any
    
    def configure(self):
        if self.settings.os != self.options.os_target:
            self.settings.os = self.options.os_target
        if self.settings.arch != self.options.arch_target:
            self.settings.arch = self.options.arch_target

    def requirements(self):
        self.requires('libc/1.0', visible=True)

    def package_info(self):
        sysroot = self.dependencies["libc"].package_folder
        self.output.highlight(f"sysroot exporting path at {sysroot}")
        self.conf_info.define("user.sysroot.root", sysroot)
```

*`libc/conanfile.py`*

```py
import os
from typing import Any
from conan import ConanFile

class RuntimeConanfile(ConanFile):
    name : Any = "libc"
    version : Any = "1.0"
    description : Any = "c runtime library"
    license : Any = "TBD"
    homepage : Any = "TBD"
    settings : Any = ("os", "arch")
    tool_requires : Any

    def build_requirements(self):
        # require the version of the compiler that does not have a libc baked in, 
        # since this recipe is for building libc
        self.tool_requires("cc/1.0", options={"libc": False})
```

Comment: I would suggest you looking at https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/master/recipes/gcc/all/conanfile.py first. There is an effort on adding gcc to Conan Center.

Comment: Is this the same as the issue reported in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/13469?

Comment: @drodri yes.  i linked to here form there.

Comment: @uilianries, thanks, that's a good starting point for gcc, but it doesn't model the glibc part of a cross compiler build.

Comment: @LawrenceD'Anna for glibc I would recommend reading https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/3972 because it's well discussed topic.

Comment: @uilianries that’s a very interesting discussion, but it’s not really related directly to what I’m asking about here. I’m talking about modeling the build process of bootstrapping a gcc Cross ccompiler, not modeling compatibility requirements between different versions off glibc